# File download prevention

Tags: php, download

I have a project where client will be uploading his songs to the web and afterwards, play those in website.

There are many tools out there that allow to download all kinds of media, even if it is considered hidden and so on. One of the tools is DownloadHelper addon for Firefox.

How can I prevent tools like this to download my media files? But, I should be able to freely use these files in front-end for promotional purposes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *If you can hear it you can snag it* -- (improvised) tagline of a software that lets you record just about anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) RTMP instead of HTTP (i.e., streaming audio/video data from server instead of downloading file); you will need FMS, Red5 or similar software on server; this still can be recorded by using RTMP streamers and/or line-out recorders.

2) Add some unique session-based identifier so that file (or stream in RTMP case) can be accessed by the same URL only once; next request of the same URL would be invalid. E.g., in your PHP file, set

```
$_SESSION['file_unique_stuff'] = rand(1000000, 9999999);
<a href='<?php echo "file.php?file_id={$file_id}&amp;unique_stuff={$_SESSION['file_unique_stuff']}"; ?>'>file</a>
```

And then in the file that passes content to client (`file.php`):

```
if ( empty($_GET['unique_stuff']) || empty($_SESSION['file_unique_stuff']) || $_GET['unique_stuff'] != $_SESSION['file_unique_stuff'] ) ) {
    header("Status: 404 Not Found");
    exit;
}
// session's "unique stuff" is validated and is not needed anymore
unset($_SESSION['file_unique_stuff']);
// pass file to client
//...
```

For the best results, combine both methods. Do this for every file, i.e., you'll probably have array of "unique stuffs" (`$_SESSION[$file_id]['unique_stuff']`) instead of single value (`$_SESSION['file_unique_stuff']`).

You could also hide `file_id` completely from URL by linking it to some random hash value in session, i.e., store `$_SESSION[$hash] = $file_id` and use URL `?hash={$hash}`.

It's not 100% safe, but that's the best you can do in web, as there is no way to ensure that user does not use any 3rd party tool.

Comment: Great solution, but I guess I'll just talk the client over to forget about his super secure ideas, since it involves a bit more work than usual. P.S. Sveiciens latviešiem! :)

Comment: While implementing RTMP might be PITA, 2nd method is not that difficult to implement. You'll need only (1) a list of files (either stored in DB or as PHP array, if the list is small and rarely changes) which maps filenames to numerical ID, (2) PHP file that passes file's contents to browser (`file.php` file in my answer) and (3) less than 10 lines of code for generating unique URLs in each page request and validating these URLs. P.S. greetings from LV ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use something other than HTTP/HTTPS to stream your audio. [RTSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol)/[RTMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol) may be. You can use Flash player as a front-end for the latter.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. If they can see/watch/hear it, generally it is already on the user's computer.

They can always record their audio stream too.

Perhaps try using 30 second samples or low bit rate versions.

Comment: Well, audio stream is for more-advanced users, every day user won't bother doing this. But some are aware of DownloadHelper and similar tools. P.S. That's not my audio stream, that's for a project and client demands this. Plus, I've seen sites with behaviour like this, for instance - Grooveshark.

Answer (score 1):

There have been a number of attempts to block that kind of downloading, either by slicing the media file into multiple chunks and only streaming one at a time or by adding layers of Flash in between the file and the client.  Services like Hulu also have robust implementations for blocking video downloaders.

In general, developing that type of system is extremely time-consuming and often takes a lot of cloud capacity to do on the fly.  At the end of the day it's not going to be 100% secure anyway, maybe it would be better to limit their access through extra Flash work or other plugins.