# How to lock (or make impossible) media downloads from web site

Tags: http, web, html5-audio, audio-streaming

When I go to other websites like Soundcloud, audiomack... I can see the link of the audio from the web dev tool [from Firefox], if I click those links I can download the songs. Why from Spotify I can't play the downloaded songs, but the browser can? I would like to create a website that makes it impossible to download the medias.

Note: I can download the audio file. I open the audio file from Vlc and it shows the exact total time that is in the web. But VLC cannot play the hole song, but the browser or Spotify web player can.

[image]

Comment: I would suggest adjusting the title to something like: `How to lock (or make impossible) media downloads from web site`, since this is your *real* question. Then you can reference Spotify as an example in the also reworded question. I think you may get better response this way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File Download Prevention](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6172941/62576)

Comment: @KenWhite What technology used by Spotify? because it's possible to download from RTMP. And I don't want to use Flash player.

Comment: I don't know what Spotify uses, and asking that question here is off-topic. If you can't find it from the page source, contact Spotify and ask them what they're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s called digital rights management, or DRM. Chrome uses widevine, safari uses FairPlay and Microsoft has playready.

Comment: You're right. I just disable DRM on Firefox and the songs from Spotify cannot be played. And Firefox uses CDM Google Widevine. And there are tools that can download DRM streams.